# Page not displaying correctly on first load when javascript has been enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is not a massive problem as it only seems to happen when changing the settings and reloading the page, but it's bugging me as I don't understand why it should be happening. It seems alright on firefox, but chrome is having problems.

If I disable javascript then refresh the page, it prints `<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role=alert>...stuff....</div>`, but then if I refresh the page a second time, it displays it correctly.
The close button has the same problem, just it works the other way around.

Working normally:
[image]

Disable JS and refresh (code is displayed as text):
[image]

Refresh:
[image]

Enable JS and refresh (no close option):
[image]

Refresh:
[image]

Here's the code I have:

```
<head>
    <noscript>
        <style>
            #javascript_close{display:none;}
        </style>
    </noscript>
</head>

 <body>
    <noscript>
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role=alert>
            <h4>JavaScript is disabled!</h4>
            <p>stuff here.</p>
        </div>
    </noscript>

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role=alert>
        <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=alert aria-label=Close id="javascript_close">
            <span aria-hidden=true>&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4>Sorry! We found a few problems!</h4>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Error:</span> Something is empty.</p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Error:</span> Something else is invalid.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Here's the page](http://poa.comeze.com/parking/main) it's on if anyone wants to try (apologies about the source code, I generate it all with PHP so it's missing line breaks). It's not a big problem as it seems to work fine if you don't touch the javascript settings, but now that I know about it it's a little annoying, so if there's a quick fix anyone has I'd appreciate it

Comment: The close button has that ID if that's what you mean, it does work, just with chrome it's 1 reload behind